# Function call using import in web2py

Tags: python, function, import, call, web2py

I have split the code into multiple files. I have imported all the functions from all other files into admin.py. Lets say I want to call a function XYZ. If I give path to function as `admin/XYZ` it gives me error as invalid function and for this I have to give the path as `file_with_XYZ_function/XYZ`.

Is there a way to overcome this problem and simple call all the imported functions from one single file

Comment: do you have XYZ as a filename?

Comment: Which code? Your code? Is admin.py your own function or did you change the gluon/admin.py core file? Where is the file admin/XYZ, under yourapp/modules? I am sorry but we need more info. You will get better support if you ask on the web2py mailing list.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, i have edited the question itself.
admin.py is my own file (in controllers) and i have imported a function which is XYZ in that file. I cannot call that function in the same way as i call the functions defined in admin.py

Comment: Note, web2py controller (and model) files are not Python modules, so you don't import from them. You should put modules in the /app/modules folder. What are you trying to achieve? Are you just trying to put your functions into multiple controller files for organization purposes, but you only want one controller name in your URLs? In that case, you may be able to achieve your goal via the URL rewrite functionality.

Comment: Thanks for URL rewrite functionality, this is exactly i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This might not be answering your question as I'm not sure I understand your question...

But if you want to put some code into a (shared) module and include it from several of your controllers I suggest that you have a look at chapter four (*The Core*) of the [web2py book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04) and search for `local_import`.

> For this kind of situation, web2py
>   provides another way to import modules
>   in such a way that the global sys.path
>   is not altered: by placing them in the
>   "modules" folder of an application.
>   One side benefit is that the module
>   will be automatically copied and
>   distributed with the application;
>   however, there are certain
>   restrictions that apply. web2py
>   provides a local_import function that
>   must be used to import modules from
>   the "modules" folder.

The import of modules depends on the modules and where web2py can find them. If it is a standard module which web2py can find in sys.path or in web2py/site-packages `import modulename` should work as expected.

For modules local to your app web2py offers something else: `applications/appname/modules`

Those modules can be imported using `local_import`.

`mymodule = local_import(themodule)`

This imports the module with the name themodule in the apps local modules folder and makes it available under the name mymodule. Note that local_import supports two additional arguments: reload and app.  During development module code often changes so don't forget to tell web2py to reload the module upon each request with the parameter `reload=True`, otherwise you won't see your changes unless you restart web2py.

Comment: Note, as of web2py 1.96.1, local_import has been deprecated. You can now import modules from the /app/modules folder using standard Python import statements. E.g., for /app/modules/mymodule.py, simply do `import mymodule`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create python files in modules folder and import them just like how you import python libraries in your controllers. But you have to give the path to those files like

```
 from applications.myApp.modules.myModule import *
```

this is my solution for my wrappers. now you can use your functions by calling their name

```
myFunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you are telling is true if i have to call that function from somewhere within the file. If i want to use same functions directly from the file in which i have imported them, it gives no such function found (you can refer to my question for more details.)

Comment: you cant call those functions like the native functions in the file because those functions you import are imported on runtime thus your server cannot direct the requests to those functions ,as they dont exist for it. You can rather place dummy functions that call those imported functions inside, as last resort. everything is something happened.

Comment: That is where we use URL rewrite :)