# Add a newline after each closing html tag in web2py

Tags: regex, web2py

**Original**

I want to parse a string of html code and add newlines after closing tags + after the initial form tag. Here's the code so far. It's giving me an error in the "re.sub" line. I don't understand why the regex fails.

```py
def user(): 
    tags = "<form><label for=\"email_field\">Email:</label><input type=\"email\" name=\"email_field\"/><label for=\"password_field\">Password:</label><input type=\"password\" name=\"password_field\"/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\"/></form>"
    result = re.sub("(</.*?>)", "\1\n", tags)
    return dict(form_code=result)
```

PS. I have a feeling this might not be the best way... but I still want to learn how to do this.

**EDIT**

I was missing "import re" from my default.py. Thanks ruakh for this.

```py
import re
```

Now my page source code shows up like this (inspected in client browser). The actual page shows the form code as text, not as UI elements.

```html
&lt;form&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;email_field&quot;&gt;Email:&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;email&quot; name=&quot;email_field&quot;/&gt;&lt;label     
for=&quot;password_field&quot;&gt;Password:&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;password&quot; name=&quot;password_field&quot;/&gt;&lt;input   
type=&quot;submit&quot; value=&quot;Login&quot;/&gt;&lt;/form&gt;
```

**EDIT 2**

The form code is rendered as UI elements after adding XML() helper into default.py. Thanks Anthony for helping. Corrected line below:

```py
return dict(form_code=XML(result))
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Fixing the regex I figured myself. This is not optimal solution but at least it works. The final code:

```py
import re
def user(): 
    tags = "<form><label for=\"email_field\">Email:</label><input type=\"email\" name=\"email_field\"/><label for=\"password_field\">Password:</label><input type=\"password\" name=\"password_field\"/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\"/></form>"
    tags = re.sub(r"(<form>)", r"<form>\n  ", tags)
    tags = re.sub(r"(</.*?>)", r"\1\n  ", tags)
    tags = re.sub(r"(/>)", r"/>\n  ", tags)
    tags = re.sub(r"(  </form>)", r"</form>\n", tags)
    return dict(form_code=XML(tags))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see is that you need to change `"\1\n"` to `r"\1\n"` (using the "raw" string notation); otherwise `\1` is interpreted as an octal escape (meaning the character U+0001). But that shouldn't give you an *error*, per se. What error-message are you getting?

Comment: It gives: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>(global name 're' is not defined)

Comment: The same result with r applied, btw

Comment: I assume that just means you need to `import re`. (Disclaimer: that's what you would need in regular Python. I've never used web2py, and I have a vague sense that imports might work a bit differently there. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557000/problem-in-function-call-using-import-in-web2py. But as a first step, I'd try just putting `import re` above your function-definition and seeing if it fixes the issue.)

Comment: Zillion thanks! Now the page shows up. However, the output is still not correctly formatted. I'll update the original question with my findings.

Comment: No, imports work as usual in web2py. In the past, there was an issue specifically with modules in the application's "modules" folder that required a special import method, but that is no longer the case. Imports of modules in sys.path (such as the standard library) have always worked as usual in web2py.

Answer (score 1):

By default, web2py escapes all text inserted in the view for security reasons. To avoid that, simply use the [XML()](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#XML) helper, either in the controller:

```
return dict(form_code=XML(result))
```

or in the view:

```
{{=XML(form_code)}}
```

Don't do this unless the code is coming from a trusted source -- otherwise it could contain malicious Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! My form is now correctly displayed. XML() did the magic. Last issue: the regex pattern is only partially ok.